# ISNULL giving wrong value in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a scenario to check if first variable is null then shows to another variable value,for that i am using `ISNULL` but it gives wrong value.I don't know is wrong in my code given below :

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(5) = NULL,
        @str2 VARCHAR(10) = 'SQL Strings';

PRINT ISNULL(@str1, @str2);
```

But it print only `SQL S`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is because the type is determined by the first column, even if it is `NULL`.  If you do:

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
        @str2 VARCHAR(10) = 'SQL Strings';

PRINT ISNULL(@str1, @str2);
```

Then you will get the expected answer.

The documentation says:

> Replacement_value
>
> Is the expression to be returned if check_expression is NULL. replacement_value must be of a type that is implicitly convertible to the type of check_expresssion.

In other words, the second value is always converted to the first type.  As a note, this is different from `coalesce()` where SQL Server tries harder to determine the type.  So, `coalesce(@str1, @str2)` does what you expect (see [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/42145)).

Answer (score 2):

ISNULL() Returns same data type as check_expression, (1st arguement). Since it is only 5 characters the string is truncated:

You need to use COALESCE instead:

```
DECLARE @str1 VARCHAR(5) = NULL,
        @str2 VARCHAR(10) = 'SQL Strings';

PRINT COALESCE(@str1, @str2);
PRINT ISNULL(@str1, @str2);
```